# Can't change frame size of LPLinkView in a SwiftUI List

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to display rich links in a SwiftUI List and no matter what I try, I can't seem to be able to change the size of the link view (UIViewRepresentable) on screen.

Is there a minimum size for a particular link?  And how can I get it.  Adding .aspectRatio and clipped() will respect size but the link is heavily clipped.  Not sure why the link will not adjust aspectRatio to fit view.

Some of the following code is sourced from the following tutorial:
https://www.appcoda.com/linkpresentation-framework/

I am using the following UIViewRepresentable for the LinkView:

```
import SwiftUI
import LinkPresentation

struct LinkViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
 
    typealias UIViewType = LPLinkView
    
    var metadata: LPLinkMetadata?
 
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> LPLinkView {
        guard let metadata = metadata else { return LPLinkView() }
        let linkView = LPLinkView(metadata: metadata)
        return linkView
    }
 
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: LPLinkView, context: Context) {

    }
}
```

And my view with List is:

```
import SwiftUI
import LinkPresentation

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var linksViewModel = LinksViewModel()
    
    var links: [(String, String)] = [("https://www.apple.com", "1"), ("https://www.stackoverflow.com", "2")]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(links, id: \.self.1) { link in
                    VStack {
                        Text(link.0)
                            .onAppear {
                                linksViewModel.getLinkMetadata(link: link)
                            }
                        if let richLink = linksViewModel.links.first(where: { $0.id == link.1 }) {
                            if let metadata = richLink.metadata {
                                if metadata.url != nil {
                                    LinkViewRepresentable(metadata: metadata)
                                        .frame(width: 200)  // setting frame dimensions here has no effect
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Setting the frame of the view or contentMode(.fit) or padding or anything else I've tried does not change the size of the frame of the LinkViewRepresentable.  I have tried sizeToFit in the representable on update and no luck.  Is it possible to control the size of the representable view here?

Here are additional Files:

```
import Foundation
import LinkPresentation

class LinksViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var links = [Link]()
    
    init() {
        loadLinks()
    }
    
    func createLink(with metadata: LPLinkMetadata, id: String) {
        let link = Link()
        link.id = id
        link.metadata = metadata
        links.append(link)
        saveLinks()
    }
    
    
    fileprivate func saveLinks() {
        do {
            let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: links, requiringSecureCoding: true)
            guard let docDirURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
            try data.write(to: docDirURL.appendingPathComponent("links"))
            print(docDirURL.appendingPathComponent("links"))
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    
    fileprivate func loadLinks() {
        guard let docDirURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
        let linksURL = docDirURL.appendingPathComponent("links")
        
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: linksURL.path) {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: linksURL)
                guard let unarchived = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? [Link] else { return }
                links = unarchived
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchMetadata(for link: String, completion: @escaping (Result<LPLinkMetadata, Error>) -> Void) {

        guard let uRL = URL(string: link) else { return }
        let metadataProvider = LPMetadataProvider()
        metadataProvider.startFetchingMetadata(for: uRL) { (metadata, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                completion(.failure(error))
                return
            }
            if let metadata = metadata {
                completion(.success(metadata))
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getLinkMetadata(link: (String, String)) {
        for storedLink in self.links {
            if storedLink.id != link.1 {
                return
            }
        }
        do {
            let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
            let matches = detector.matches(in: link.0, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: link.0.utf16.count))
            if let match = matches.first {
                guard let range = Range(match.range, in: link.0) else { return }
                let uRLString = link.0[range]
                
                self.fetchMetadata(for: String(uRLString)) { result in
                    self.handleLinkFetchResult(result, link: link)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    private func handleLinkFetchResult(_ result: Result<LPLinkMetadata, Error>, link: (String, String)) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch result {
                case .success(let metadata):
                self.createLink(with: metadata, id: link.1)
                case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And Link Class:

```
import Foundation
import LinkPresentation

class Link: NSObject, NSSecureCoding, Identifiable {
    
    var id: String?
    var metadata: LPLinkMetadata?
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    // MARK: - NSSecureCoding Requirements
    
    static var supportsSecureCoding = true

    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        guard let id = id, let metadata = metadata else { return }
        coder.encode(id, forKey: "id")
        coder.encode(metadata as NSObject, forKey: "metadata")
    }
 
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        id = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "id") as? String
        metadata = coder.decodeObject(of: LPLinkMetadata.self, forKey: "metadata")
    }
}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: where u used to get the `makeUIView`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Your code works for me (with minor mods for my simple tests, since all info is not available). 
Changing `.frame(width: 100)` to, for example, `.frame(width: 300)` works.
On macos 12.1-beta, using xcode 13.2-beta. Tested on real devices, iOS-15, Catalyst-12.1.

Comment: I have updated with all files.  Not working for me.

Comment: Using your code as is, still works for me.
Changing `.frame(width: 100)` to `.frame(width: 300)` works. 
On macos 12.1-beta, using xcode 13.2-beta. Tested on real devices, iOS-15, Catalyst-12.1.
It may be different on older system. What system are you using?

Comment: Updated with picture of 100 frame reference. I'm on a 2021 MacBook Pro Monterey 12.0.1, Xcode  Version 13.1 (13A1030d) Testing on simulator iPod touch (but same on all sims I have tested) iOS 15

Comment: just tested on device iPhone12 Pro Max  iOS 15.1.1 and same result as simulator.  It appears the link view disregards the frame

Comment: I may have misunderstood your comments.  Some link sizes may work for some links but I want to know why I can't consistently control frame size for all links.  Whether it's 100, 300 or any other value.  Is there a minimum?  The links on apple message app are much smaller than the ones I'm able to achieve.

Comment: The picture you have with `.frame(width: 100)` is what I get, **except** that 
for me **both** the "www.example.com" and the "Where Developers..." are of the same size (100).
If I change to `.frame(width: 300)` or 400, then they both become must wider, 
and both take the width of the iPhone.

Comment: That’s odd.  Not sure why it would be different.  Unless it is something to do with the beta Xcode version you are using. Maybe I will install and try it on that.

Comment: Note that if I use `.frame(width: 20)` then they look like they are size 100.
So definitely there is a minimum limit, for me anyway.

Comment: Thx for your help.  I’ll keep plugging away until I figure out how to have some control over the layout.   I did manage to make it work using an nslayout constraint in the makeview of the represebtsvkr for width.  But using auto layout there causes other problems positioning the view.

Comment: @alionthego managed to find a solution for this? Setting the `widthAnchor` doesn't seem to work unless `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` is used which leads to other issues thrown on the console

Comment: The only fix I found was setting an explicit height and width which doesn’t really work for me because I want to only set width only But if that works for you I did that by subclassing the linkview and setting override intrinsicContenySize and defining your size there.

Comment: @alionthego thanks, let me see that will fit my needs

Comment: sure.  I've included that as an answer below although it doesn't really work for me as I need a dynamic height.

Comment: @alionthego I have added some comments, if you can make the changes that would be great to prevent the crash and to make the height dynamic. Hopefully it solves your problem of dynamic height

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was subclassing the linkView overriding the intrinsic content size.  Thanks to user1046037's comment, using super.intrinsicContentSize.height will enable it to work dynamically.

```
import SwiftUI
import LinkPresentation

class CustomLinkView: LPLinkView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { CGSize(width: 0, height: super.intrinsicContentSize.height) }
}

struct LinkViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
 
    typealias UIViewType = CustomLinkView
    
    var metadata: LPLinkMetadata?
 
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomLinkView {
        guard let metadata = metadata else { return CustomLinkView() }
        let linkView = CustomLinkView(metadata: metadata)
        return linkView
    }
 
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CustomLinkView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one! could you make 2 small changes, your code crashes, I had to initialise using URL (to prevent crash) and also you could return `CGSize(width: 0, height: super.intrinsicContentSize.height)` without hard coding the sizes. That would make it dynamic. Nice work!

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  you really helped solve the dynamic height issue I was struggling so much with and it works very well now.  I wasn't sure about the crash you mentioned initializing with URL.  Mine is not crashing.  Did you mean you are initializing the CustomLinkView with URL instead of Metadata?  Mine is working fine initializing with Metadata

Comment: oh ok, may be the way I am using it is slightly different, anyway, it would take 24 hours to grant you the bounty, will do in 24 hours. Nice work once again.

Comment: and thank you also for the help polishing it off and making it work properly.

Comment: You did most of the work :)

Comment: I just experienced the crash you mentioned with respect to metadata.  that occurs when the metadata is not nil but the url property of metadata is nil.  For now I just added a conditional nil check for the metadata.url to solve that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240563/discussion-between-user1046037-and-alionthego).

Comment: for what this line of code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212090/cant-change-frame-size-of-lplinkview-in-a-swiftui-list#:~:text=typealias%20UIViewType%20%3D%20CustomLinkView

Answer (score 1):

**Here is my LinkPresentation code example in SwiftUI**

```
import SwiftUI
import LinkPresentation
```

**Custom Class, to resize internal content**

```
class CustomLinkView: LPLinkView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        CGSize(width: super.intrinsicContentSize.width,
               height: super.intrinsicContentSize.height)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel Class (not the best approach for SwiftUI)**

```
class LPMeatDataProvider_VM: ObservableObject {

    private let stringURLs: [String] = [
        "https://medium.com", "https://apple.com",
        "https://yahoo.com", "https://stackoverflow.com"
    ]

    @Published var URLs: [URL] = []

    init() { getURLs() }

    func getURLs() {
        stringURLs.forEach { string in
            guard let url = URL(string: string) else { return }
            URLs.append(url)
       }
    }
}
```

**View & UIViewRepresentable**

```
struct URLPreviewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var togglePreview: Bool

    var previewURL: URL

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomLinkView {
        let view = CustomLinkView(url: previewURL)
        let provider = LPMetadataProvider()
        provider.startFetchingMetadata(for: previewURL) { metadata, error in
            if error == nil, let metadata = metadata {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    view.metadata = metadata
                    togglePreview.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CustomLinkView, context: Context) {}
}

struct LPMeatDataProvider_: View {

    @State var togglePreview = false
    @StateObject var vm = LPMeatDataProvider_VM()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(vm.URLs, id: \.self) { _url in
                    URLPreviewContainer(togglePreview: $togglePreview, previewURL: _url)
                        .padding()
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I share with you my option. I'm just created customizable, custom preview for URL for SwiftUI with help of LPMetadataProvider.

It is only for preview purposes, I'm not adding an option to open it in Safari (otherwise it easy to achieve).

[image]

I created Observable object, i.e view model for my view. Inside it I pass url and then retrieve metadata for needed pieces (image, title, host).

```
final class PreviewViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var image: UIImage?
@Published var title: String?
@Published var url: String?

let previewURL: URL?

init(_ url: String) {
    self.previewURL = URL(string: url)
    
    initMetada()
}

private func initMetada() {
    guard let previewURL else { return }
    let provider = LPMetadataProvider()
    
    Task {
        let metadata = try await provider.startFetchingMetadata(for: previewURL)
        
        image = try await convertToImage(metadata.imageProvider)
        title = metadata.title
        
        if #available(iOS 16, *) {
            url = metadata.url?.host()
        } else {
            url = metadata.url?.host
        }
    }
}

private func convertToImage(_ imageProvider: NSItemProvider?) async throws -> UIImage? {
    var image: UIImage?
    
    if let imageProvider {
        let type = String(describing: UTType.image)
        
        if imageProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(type) {
            let item = try await imageProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: type)
            
            if item is UIImage {
                image = item as? UIImage
            }
            
            if item is URL {
                guard let url = item as? URL,
                      let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else { return nil }
                
                image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
            
            if item is Data {
                guard let data = item as? Data else { return nil }
                
                image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
    }
    
    return image
}
}
```

In view just adopted my view model, set up for my preference image, title, etc.

```
    struct FileLinkView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: PreviewViewModel
    
    let action: () -> ()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
            HStack(spacing: 15) {
                if let image = viewModel.image {
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(maxWidth: 107, maxHeight: 107)
                        .clipped()
                        .cornerRadius(16)
                }
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1, content: {
                    if let title = viewModel.title {
                        Text(title)
                            .font(.CreatePost.previewTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(.codGray)
                    }
                    
                    if let url = viewModel.url {
                        Text(url)
                            .font(.smallFont)
                            .foregroundColor(.santasGray)
                    }
                })
                .padding(.top, 16)
                .padding(.bottom, 9)
                .padding(.trailing, 40)
            }
            
            Button(action: action, label: {
                Image.CreatePost.deleteIcon
            })
            .padding([.top, .trailing], 8)
        }
    }
}

    struct FileLinkView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            FileLinkView(
                viewModel: PreviewViewModel("https://www.f1news.ru/news/f1-168537.html"),
                action: {}
            )
        }
    }
```